# Cannot get SharedPreferences in View Adapter returns null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to get shared preferencess in view adapter class using context but it returns null.

What I've tried is:

how can i get login parameter to adapter in getitemviewtype?

i edited code as belows

any help would be good

```
import static android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences;

public class ChattAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Chatt> moviesList;
     Context context;
public String loginx;
    public TextView title, year, genre;
    public CardView cardViewphoto;
    public ImageView resim;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM0 = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 1;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView titlem, yearm, genrem;
        public CardView cardViewphoto;
        public ImageView resim;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            titlem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genrem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            yearm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
            resim= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        }

    }
    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;
        public CardView cardViewphoto;
        public ImageView resim;


        public ViewHolder0(View v) {
            super(v);

            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titlesender);
            genre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.genresender);
            year = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yearsender);
           // resim= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        }    }



    public ChattAdapter(List<Chatt> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }





    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        context = parent.getContext();

        pref =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginx = pref.getString("user", null);
        Log.d("prefsss",loginx.toString());
       // login= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().toString();
        if (viewType == 1 ){
            return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row, parent, false));
        }
        else{

            return new ViewHolder0(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row2, parent, false));

        }

        // View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_list_row, parent, false);


        //return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position ) {
        // Here you have to write logic for which position have which type of row and return the same
        Chatt love = moviesList.get(position);
        Log.d("law",love.getTitle().toString());
        Log.d("prefsss",loginx.toString());

        //Log.d("law",login);
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
       //  pref =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       // login = pref.getString("user", null);


        if( love.getTitle().equals(loginx)){

           return 2;
       }else{


           return 1;

       }


    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {




Log.d("lawtayp",String.valueOf(holder.getItemViewType()) );
            if (holder.getItemViewType()==2){
                ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;
                Chatt love = moviesList.get(position);

             //   viewHolder0.title.setText(love.getTitle());
              //  viewHolder0.genre.setText(love.getGenre());
                viewHolder0.year.setText(love.getYear());
                // Picasso.with(getClass()).load("http://barronpw.alwaysdata.net/p/"+name+".png").into(cardViewphoto);
               // Picasso.with(context).load("http://barronpw.alwaysdata.net/p/"+love.getTitle() +".png").into(viewHolder0.resim);


            }else{


                // code to populate type 1 view here
                MyViewHolder myviewholder = (MyViewHolder)holder;
                Chatt love = moviesList.get(position);

                // Chatt love = moviesList.get(position);

               // myviewholder.titlem.setText(love.getTitle());
               // myviewholder.genrem.setText(love.getGenre());
                myviewholder.yearm.setText(love.getYear());
                // Picasso.with(getClass()).load("http://barronpw.alwaysdata.net/p/"+name+".png").into(cardViewphoto);
               Picasso.with(context).load("http://barronpw.alwaysdata.net/p/"+love.getTitle() +"-p.png").into(myviewholder.resim);
            }



            // Code to populate type 0 view here




    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(context);`?

Comment: yes but it says                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: @barann ; why`context.getApplicationContext()`? why not only `context`?

Comment: i tried that it still returns null

Comment: The way you obtain the context is bad. You're supposed to get the context coming from the activity by passing through constructor. Getting the context on the onCreateViewHolder will result to multiple re-referencing because it will be called base on the number ViewHolder it creates at the same time it also creates an unecessary new objects.

Comment: how can i reach login from getitemviewtype it returns null otherwise i can get login parameter and context in oncreateviewholder but cant pass it to getitemviewtype

Comment: Will you post your entire Adapter code? It's hard to answer the question base on that short snippet and we have no idea whats the usecase of the app.

Comment: okay please check , i just need loginx variable from sharedprefs in viewtypeswitch

Comment: solved with this from activity ...        mAdapter = new ChattAdapter(getApplicationContext(),me,me2,movieList); and inside adapter 

    public ChattAdapter(Context context,String me,String anon,List<Chatt> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
this.context=context;
        this.me=me;
        this.me2=me2;



    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the context which should be within the application so that the shared preference can be read properly. One way to do so is to pass the activity/fragment's context as additional argument to the adapter with the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class ChattAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Chatt> moviesList;
     Context context;
public String loginx;
    public TextView title, year, genre;
    public CardView cardViewphoto;
    public ImageView resim;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM0 = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 1;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView titlem, yearm, genrem;
        public CardView cardViewphoto;
        public ImageView resim;

public ChattAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
}
....

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // context = parent.getContext();

        pref =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor :

```
    public ChattAdpater(Context context){
  prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     }
```

remove prefs initialisation from onCreateViewHolder